# As an system administrator, how can i view other user profiles from their perspective?

Tags: administration

I am sure this will be terribly simple but here goes . . 
I basically want to be able to go into a user profile (eg . . Sales person lets say) and view sales force as they would see it. This is because i need to create a user guide for a specific set of users, which wouldn't be much help from my view!
Thanks very much all.

Comment: Do you not see the "login" options besides users in setup>mange>users ? What edition are you on ?

Comment: I've upvoted Michael's answer but as a side note - you probably should be preparing training materials in sandbox (depends how sensitive data you'll show on the screenshots). You should be already able to login as anybody in sandbox and if not - change their email & password and hack at it.

Answer (score 8):

You may need to contact support to turn on the ability to log in as all users.

http://blogs.salesforce.com/product/2012/06/log-in-as-any-user-without-first-having-access-granted-new-feature-in-summer-12.html